# Compile C programs with Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

Can I use Visual Studio 2005 to compile simple C programs? There appears to be only options to create projects for VB, C# or C++. If this is possible, what do I need to do?

Comment: Related: [How to develop C with Visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5770919)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To give you a more concrete answer, Visual Studio will definitely compile C code under a C++ project.  It will even compile it as C code, not C++ - Visual Studio treats anything with a .c extension as C code and will compile as such by default.  This is confirmed in the documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384838.aspx) (albeit only specified for VS2008 and VS2010).  There is even a compiler command line switch (`/Tc`) and an option in the properties page of any .c file to compile it as C++ code, rather than the C default.

Answer (score 2):

My try to give graphical feedback on question. The screen shots taken from the properties dialog of a project (1PassCompilerFixNotation) and a source file (emitter.c) in Visual Studio 2008, should be identical with VS 2005.

For The Whole Project:

Right click on the projects node in Solution Explorer and select "Properties"

By setting the entry "Compile As" in the "Advanced" tab, syntax and semantic can be changed between

- **Compile as C Code (/TC)**
- **Compile as C++ Code (/TP)**

for the project. (See image below)

[image]

For A Specific File:

Right click on a C/C++ file in Solution Explorer and select "Properties"

By setting the entry "Compile As" in the "Advanced" tab, syntax and semantic can be changed between

- **Compile as C Code (/TC)**
- **Compile as C++ Code (/TP)**

for a specific file. (See image below)

**Note:** Specific file settings superseeds project default settings.

[image: Compilersettings in Visual-Studio 2008]

Comment: You're right, this works fine. But even easier is just to use the `.c` file extension. VS automatically compiles such files as C code if you leave this at the default setting.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 comes with a solid C89/90 compiler. There are no issues using C in VS2005. Files with `.c` extension will be automatically compiled as C files. (Or you can override the language by using project settings/command line switches as described in other answers).

Just keep in mind, again, that VS compilers only support the "classic" C89/90. There's no support for C99 features (not even mentioning C11).

Answer (score 1):

In general, C is a subset of C++.  For a simple C program, just call it a C++ project.  I don't have a copy of the software handy, but the odds are if you create a file with the '.c' extension, it'll be treated as C. *[I should possibly have added: "... as it did in the versions of Visual Studio and Visual C++ that I've used since the early '90s.]*

**Update**: for @R, who isn't as up to date on his programming languages as he thinks:

> C++ is a *direct descendant of C that
>   retains almost all of C as a subset.*
>   C++ provides stronger type checking
>   than C and directly supports a wider
>   range of programming styles than C.
>   C++ is "a better C" in the sense that
>   it supports the styles of programming
>   done using C with better type checking
>   and more notational support (without
>   loss of efficiency). In the same
>   sense, ANSI C is a better C than K&R
>   C. In addition, C++ supports data
>   abstraction, object-oriented
>   programming, and generic programming
>   (see The C++ Programming Language (3rd
>   Edition)"; Appendix B discussing
>   compatibility issues is available for
>   downloading). [Emphasis mine.]

The author of that statement is a fellow with some understanding of C++, by the name of [Bjarne](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq.html#difference).  And before you try to save yourself by pickily noting the "almost all of", read what I wrote: "*In general*, C..."

Comment: C is not remotely a subset of C++. And guesswork is not an answer.

Comment: To further elaborate and explain my -1, teaching a novice C coder to compile their C code with a C++ compiler is perhaps the worst advice you can give, unless your goal is to make them hate C. The intersection of C and C++ is a language with all of the disadvantages of C++ versus C, and none of the advantages. If nothing else, someone who follows your advice will end up misusing `malloc`, and might very well write code that fails on a real C compiler due to issues like the type and size of character literals or promotion issues.

Comment: Actually, R, teaching a novice to use a C++ compiler is one of the best things that can happen to them.  C++ enforces a lot of things lint is needed for in plain C.  But, if you read my actual ANSWEER, you'll note that I suggest creating the file with a '.c' extension, which causes it to be treated as C.

Comment: Whatever the name of the author of the statement about C being a subset of C++, that statement is patently false. There was a time when C was loosely "subset-ish" in that regard, but that time is long gone. Making such statements today will only confuse people.

Comment: The statement is very true, given that the question is about the Microsoft Visual C++ product. It does not implement C99 or anything more modern.

Comment: The author of that statement is Bjarne Stroustrup. You may have heard of his: he invented C++.

Answer (score 0):

Select C++ console, and you should be fine. VS will tend to want to use .cpp /etc extensions, but you should be able to use.c and .h extensions,

Answer (score 0):

Just use the c++ option. You can if you wish use .c extensions rather than .cpp, but plain old c will compile just fine in a c++ project.