# How to develop C with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Is there a way to develop pure ANSI C with Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: @Atha: I fail to see how that comment is anything but an attempt to incite a flamewar. You implicitly denigrate Microsoft's C complier as "not a proper" compiler, which doesn't even seem remotely fair. You obviously don't provide any sort of support for your opinion, or even make clear that it is, in fact, an opinion. You merely have a personal preference for GCC, nothing wrong with that, of course, but there's nothing objectively more proper about GCC than cl.exe, if you can get past the fact that it's bundled alongside an IDE.

Comment: MS compiler is proper C++ compiler not a proper C compiler. Why the hell someone would want to develop C with a compiler which is not supposed to do C. MS compiler is not even fully compatible with C90.

Comment: @Atha: Once again, you make the claim that it's not a proper C compiler without providing any support for your opinion. Check my answer; it's a perfectly valid C compiler if you know what you're doing. There are areas of the spec where GCC is not fully compliant either. Arguing about those is not particularly productive. There's nothing in the documentation that says Microsoft's compiler "is not supposed to do C".

Comment: @Cody I think the differences Atha brings up are because it seems more common to run into basic compatibility issues in msvc and less often than in GCC. Even if this were not the case there are odd features of msvc that seem designed to minimize code portability where it won't immediately reduce sales. Try using any kind of wizard that makes boilerplate code it seems they make code that would choke other compilers. You might also want to search for "mscv c compliance" or "msvc vendor lockin".

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. MSDN provides some information here: [ANSI C Compliance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45aft37a.aspx).

Step one is setting the compiler to produce C code, rather than C++ code. Do that from your project's Properties. Expand the C/C++ header, and click on "Advanced". Set the "Compile As" property to "Compile as C Code" (this is the same as specifying the [`/TC` switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx) on the command line). Even easier is to just name your files with a `*.c` extension.

Step two is disabling Microsoft's extensions to the ANSI standards. These are governed by the [`/Za` and `/Ze` compiler switches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx). You can find these in your project's Properties, as well. `/Za` causes the compiler to emit an error for language constructs that are not compliant with the ANSI standard. The `/Ze` switch enables Microsoft-specific extensions; you want to make sure that this one is turned *off*.

Although I don't believe that Microsoft *fully* supports the C99 standard. See (and vote for!) [this bug report on MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/485416/support-c99), [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2007/11/05/iso-c-standard-update.aspx) from the VC++ team, and [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb1574zs.aspx) for a concrete example of where that lack of support becomes evident. It does, however, have full support for the C90 standard.

Comment: Just to note that since version 2005 /Ze switch is deprecated.

Comment: @WindRider Presumably because it's the default option. Specifying it means the same thing as *not* specifying it. That makes it rather pointless. The only switch you need is `\Za`. If it's specified, you get strict ANSI compliance; if not, you get Microsoft-specific extensions.

Comment: The /Za switch (step two in the answer) is found under properties >> C/C++ >> Language

Comment: I think VS 2012 and prior only support the C89 C Standard, except for a handfull of C99 extensions. At http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/29e5caad-a5eb-4ff7-be29-585a8ae97ae7/c-in-visual-studio is a discussion thread about it. And it mentions that MS has no plans to support any more recent C Standard.

Answer (score 3):

Via changing the file extension to .c will get you started but here are also some changes to the project file. See here for details: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829488/en-us

There is also a good podcast on that: http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Sam/C-Language-Programming-with-Visual-Studio-2010-Ultimate-Pro-or-VC-Express