# Can't compile c in visual studio 2012 part II

Tags: c, visual-studio

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761347/cant-compile-c-in-visual-studio-2012) I asked about compiling `c` where there are naming issues because `C++` has more reserved words than `C` I now realise after some renames, that was the thin end of the wedge.

Example: Test.c:

```
#include <math.h>

int test()
{
    int n = pow(10, 10);
    return n;
}
```

Because math.h in C++ defines overloads for `pow`, and none of those are `int, int` it doesn't know which to pick.

Other issues that have come up include:

1. Int is not a default type, e.g. `static x = 1;` is a fail
2. Argument types can be defined after the signature but before the body in `c`, but not `c++`

Etc. it's basically not a simple job to do the conversions on this project. Another reason I don't want to change it much is that it must still compile in another `C` compiler.

So I'm not after solutions to these problems, they are very obvious, just time consuming on this massive project. I'm after a way to compile `c` practically "as is" in visual studio, or a definiative "no this is not possible".

What I have tried:

1. Forcing c compilation via Project->Properties->C/C++->Advanced->Compile as C Code
2. Turning off extensions via Project->Properties->C/C++->Language->Disable Language Extensions

Comment: Is if the other compiler is able to deal with c++? That would make the sharing of code much easier...

Comment: which conversion is backward incompatible? introducing default type or stronger typing is not going to make troubles while compiling as c code.

Comment: Note that in C89 (which is the most recent version supported by VS, IINM), the prototype for `pow` is `double pow(double x, double y);`
`

Comment: "`static x = 1;` is a fail" also in C. "Argument types can be defined after the signature but before the body in c" Oh, so you deal with ancient, K&R style code. That's bad. But should compile as C89. What specifically does the compiler say about it?

Comment: @DanielFischer "Error: explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)"

Comment: Hrrrmff. That looks like the VS equivalent of `-Werror` being in force. Omitting the type is valid in C89, but of course a half-decent compiler will warn about it. So if you make warnings errors, it'll barf.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't like it any more that you do, but it's what I have inherited, I'd love to refactor it, but I'd rather only touch it once it's working (compiling at least), otherwise I don't know if it's my changes that are causing any issues or what. It certainly does compile fine in an old ARM compiler, presumably C89. If it was as simple as one or two problems in a few places I'd do it, but it's a massive list of hundreds of errors to work through, I'd rather it compiled this perfectly valid c code if possible.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, I'll try and turn off warnings as errors.

Comment: @DanielFischer "Treat Warnings As Errors" is "No" already.

Comment: @JohnBode yes that's what I'd expect, but it's picking up all of the C++ overloads in the C++ math.h, so is clearly not compiling as C.

Comment: Hmm. So it rejects allowed code, apparently. Just to make sure, can you check whether the code compiles with gcc or clang with `-std=c89`? And double-check that VS is indeed compiling as C?

Comment: @weston: Huh.  Wish I had access to a VS implementation, because AFAICT you're doing everything necessary to compile as C.  You've named the file with a `.c` extension, you've told the environment to compile it as C, you've disabled MS extensions, etc.

Comment: @JohnBode Thanks for input, well good to know I'm not missing anything obvious at least.

Answer (score 0):

what about pow(10.0, 10.0) or pow((double)10, (double)10)? Would it make troubles to your code?

Comment: I think the `pow` function was just an example of what kind of problems the OP is trying to solve, not the actual problem.

Comment: That's right. Like I say, the solutions are pretty straight forward, it's just there are dozens of problems like these I am coming across and this is an enormous project.