# How to get the address of floor() in VC11?

Tags: c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

For some reason, floor() is a overloaded function in VC11 even when it's compiling a C source file. In my code, "floor" is used to initialize a void pointer in a structure. It's causing an error right now because VC11 can't figure out what version of the function to use.

Comment: Post the code that you have a question about here.

Comment: I don't think you're compiling a C source file, even if you think you are...

Comment: Converting a function pointer to `void*` is non-portable, though it's likely to work.

Comment: How do you know VC11 "can't figure out what version of the function to use"? Did it print an error message? If so, what is the message? What source code did you compile? Don't make us guess what you're doing; **tell us**. Do that, and I'll withdraw my downvote. I have some thoughts about what the problem might be, but I'm not going to speculate. http://sscce.org/

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio was never known for being highly C compliant. You can [put the compiler in C mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770858/how-to-develop-c-with-visual-studio-2010), but I 'm not sure if that will fix the header file problem.

If it doesn't, a possible workaround is to detect if the compiler is C++ and cast the "value" of `floor` to the signature of the desired overload if so, for example:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
void* fp = reinterpret_cast<void*>((double (*)(double)) floor);
#else
void* fp = floor;
#endif
```

Comment: At least in C, `void* fp = floor;` is invalid; there is no implicit conversion from any pointer-to-function type to `void*`. And I'm not sure about the C++ version either; a C-style cast from any function pointer type to any other function pointer type is valid, so I don't think the cast helps resolve which `floor` you're referring to.

Comment: Also, a static cast is enough to resolve overload ambiguity. `static_cast<double (&)(double)>(floor)`