# Why is it impossible to allocate an array of an arbitrary size on the stack?

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, stack-memory

Why can't I write the following?

```
char acBuf[nSize];
```

Only to prevent the stack from overgrowing?
Or is there a possibility to do something similar, if I can ensure that I always take just a few hundred kilobytes?

As far as I know, the `std::string` uses the memory of its members to store the assigned strings, as long as they are 15 characters or less. Only if the strings are longer, it uses this memory to store the address of some heap-allocated memory, which then takes the data.

It seems like it has to be 100%ly determined, during compile-time, how the stack **will be** aligned during runtime. Is that true? Why is that?

Comment: Yes, that is true. C++ does not support VLA's.

Comment: If you're allocating to the stack, ( in theory ) all the memory for each stack frame is allocated at the start of it's scope, hence why we have dynamic storage, where memory is allocated using the free store.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike C, C++ doesn't support variable length arrays. If you want them, you can use non-standard extensions such as `alloca` or GNU extensions (supported by clang and GCC). They have their caveats, so be sure to read the manual to make sure you use them safely.

The reason the stack layout is mostly determined statically is so that the generated code has to perform fewer computations (additions, multiplications, and pointer dereferencing) to figure out where the data is on the stack. The offsets can instead be hardcoded into the generated machine code.

Comment: But when I follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5770919/1594594 I am still unable to use VLA's :(

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with preventing stack overflow, you can overflow the stack just fine with `char a[SOME_LARGE_CONSTANT]`. In C++ the array size has to be known at compile time, this is among other things needed to compute the size of structures containing arrays.

C on the other hand had Variable Length Arrays since C99, which adds an exception and allow runtime dependant size for arrays within function scope. As to why C++ does not have this? It was never adopted by a C++ standard.

Comment: But when I follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5770919/1594594 I am still unable to use VLA's :(

Comment: @Allgaeuer Microsoft Visual Studio's C implementation doesn't support VLAs.

Comment: @Allgaeuer your link mentions ANSI C which is C90. Microsoft never provided a full C99 implementation, I think they only support a subset required for C++.  The last link in that answer also mentions that VLA's are not supported.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't I write the following?
>
> ```
> char acBuf[nSize];
> ```

Those are called Variable Length Arrays (VLA's) and aren't supported by C++. The reason being that the stack is very fast but tiny compared to the free store (the heap in your words). Which means that at any moment that you add lots of elements to a VLA your stack might just overflow and you get a vague runtime exception. This can also happen with compile-time sized stack arrays but these are way easier to catch because the behaviour of the program doesn't influence their size. Which means that x doesn't have to happen after y to create a stack overflow, it's just there right off the bat. [This](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.std.c++/K_4lgA1JYeg/uXqZEYVGycMJ) covers it in more detail and rage.

Containers like `std::vector` use the free store which is way bigger and has a way to deal with over-allocation (throws `bad_alloc`).

Comment: I was about to change "detail and _rage_" to "detail and _range_" - but after reading the linked discussion, there is no typo to correct. VLAs sure bring up heated discussions!

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to take a look at alloca.h

```
   void *alloca(size_t size);
```

The alloca() function allocates size bytes of space in the stack
frame of the caller.  This temporary space is automatically freed
when the function that called alloca() returns to its caller.

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem I see with VLA in C++ is the type.

What is the type of `acBuf` in `char acBuf[nSize]` or even worse in `char acBuf[nSize][nSize]` ?

```
template <typename T> void foo(const T&);

void foo(int n)
{
    char mat[n][n];

    foo(mat);
}
```

You cannot pass that array by reference to

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void foo_on_array(const T (&a)[N]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be happy that the C++ standard discourages a dangerous practice (variable-length arrays on the stack) and instead encourages a less dangerous practice (variable-length arrays and std::vector with heap allocation).

Variable-length arrays on the stack are more dangerous because:

- The available stack space is typically 8 MB, much smaller than the 2 GB (or more) of available heap space.
- When the stack space is exhausted, the program crashes with SIGSEGV, and it requires special software such as [GNU libsigsegv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libsigsegv/) to recover from such a situation.
- In typical C++ programs, the programmer does not know whether the array length will definitely stay under a limit such as 4 MB.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I write the following?
>   `char acBuf[nSize];`

You can't do that because in C++ the lenght of the array has to be known at compile time, that's because the compiler reserves the specified memory for the array and it can not be modified during runtime. it's not about prevent a stack overflow, it's about memory layout.

If you want to make a dynamic array you should use the `new` operator so it will be stored in heap.

```
char *acBuf = new char[nsize];
```